# $K$ is compact and $x\in X$ but $x\notin K$. Show $\exists G_1,G_2$ open in $(X,d)$ s.t. $x\in G_1$ and $K\subseteq G_2$

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $K$ is a compact subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ and $x \in X$ but $x\notin K$. Show that there exist two disjoint open sets of $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $X$ such that $x\in G_1$ and $K\subseteq G_2$.

I attempted the proof as follows:

Since $K$ is compact, it is closed and bounded. Since $x\notin K$ and $K$ is closed, $x\notin \bar{K}$. This means that $d(x,K) \neq 0 \Rightarrow d(x,K) = r$ for some $r>0$. Then just take $G_1 = B(x,r/2)$ and take $$G_2 = \cup_{k\in K} B(k,r/2)$$

$G_2$ is open since the union of arbitrary open sets is open and the two sets are disjoint.

Is this correct? The question gave the following hint which I have not used any of which leads me to think I am doing something wrong:

Hint: use the version of compactness we called "having a compact topology" (this is the definition in terms of open covers) and the Hausdorf property of metric spaces".

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Your proof is correct. But you don't use boundedness of $K$, only closedness. And the phrase "it is closed and bounded" smells of danger, you might confuse that with a general characterisation of compact sets. That's not the case, this characterisation holds only in some very special spaces. Using the hint, you would in fact prove the stronger assertion that in every Hausdorff space you can separate compact sets and points outside that set by disjoint open neighbourhoods.

Comment: Ah I see. Could you give a solution involving the hint?

Comment: Your proof actually proves a different stronger assertion, that in metric spaces, you can separate closed sets and points outside by disjoint open neighbourhoods. In other words, you prove that metric spaces are completely regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct - assuming you know how to show that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are indeed disjoint.

You only used that compact subsets of metric spaces are closed in your proof, so you have effectively proved the stronger assertion that metric spaces are completely regular/$T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$.

Using the hint, you would prove a different strengthening of the assertion:

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, $K \subset X$ compact, and $x \in X\setminus K$. Then there are open sets $G_1, G_2 \subset X$ with $x \in G_1$, $K \subset G_2$ and $G_1 \cap G_2 = \varnothing$.

**Proof:** For every $y\in K$, by the Hausdorff property, there are disjoint open neighbourhoods $V_y$ of $x$ and $W_y$ of $y$. The family $\{ W_y : y \in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$, hence there is a finite subset $F \subset K$ such that $\{ W_y : y \in F\}$ still covers $K$. Then

$$G_1 := \bigcap_{y\in F} V_y$$

is an open neighbourhood of $x$, and

$$G_2 := \bigcup_{y\in F} W_y$$

is an open set containing $K$, and $G_1 \cap G_2 = \varnothing$.